# Angular documentation site switches version based on visitor's different OS?

Tags: angular

I got different docs page https://angular.io/tutorial when I visit from different PC.

There is stable angular 4 on my win 10 machine while there is stable angular 6 on Ubuntu.

So this is by-design to show you the documentation based on your OS? What is the logic? OS bound angular development?

Below is snapshot of what I see on my win and Ubuntu

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a logic that change dinamically the css classes to apply based on the browser you are using? IE: use something for Chrome, use something else for Safari?

Comment: One of those is most likely cached in your browser or similar

Comment: I was just trying to read the 6 docs but realizing the version number changed to 4 because I changed my PC and there is no 6 at all on the other PC

Comment: You are right. Clear cache and Ctrl+F5 fixed it.

Comment: Take that back.It's not cache. Now it goes back to angular 4. Ubuntu is 6. Weird. Cache is not the issue.